# How can I allow the background music from another app to continue playing while my app still plays its sounds in android.. nativescript-angular

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am working in nativescript-angular application, How can I allow the background music from another app to continue playing while my app still plays its sounds in android.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same scenario

Comment: @nategurutech No, couldn't find any solutions